# How to bind a div's text into the hidden field without using JavaScript or jQuery.?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have a div element that has some text, I want to assign that text as a value of another input which is of type hidden. I cannot use Javascript or jQuery as that script tag triggering multiple times, I want to store that text.
Here is my code that I have tried.

```html
<div id=DivDefaultValue>Hello</div>

<input type="hidden" id="hdnDefaultValue" name="hdnDefaultValue" value= document.getElementById("#DivDefaultValue").text() />
```

Comment: You need to put quotes around `document.getElementById("#DivDefaultValue").text()`

Comment: Also, you don't need the `#` in `getElementById("#DivDefaultValue")

Comment: @Rojo , you mean like this. 'document.getElementById("DivDefaultValue').text()'.?

Comment: Yeah, just like that

Comment: Do note `text()` is not a function in Javascript. You need to use `.value` or `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` (note that they are not functions!). If you want to use jQuery, it should look like this: `"$("DivDefaultValue').text()"`

Comment: What do you mean by `I cannot use Javascript or jQuery as that script tag triggering multiple times`? You are clearly trying to use Javascript in your example.

Answer (score 0):

So you cannot use `<script>` tag but can use Javascript inside other tags? Then, how about to use event listener?

```
<body onload="
    let defaultValue = document.getElementById('DivDefaultValue').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('hdnDefaultValue').value = defaultValue;
">
    <div id="DivDefaultValue">Hello</div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnDefaultValue" name="hdnDefaultValue" />
</body>
```

It can be verified by:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(() => {
        let defaultValue = document.getElementById('hdnDefaultValue');
        console.log(defaultValue.value);
    }, 1000);
</script>
```